# Convert sorted array into low high array

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

Interview question: 
Given a sorted array of this form :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

( A better example would be  10,20,35,42,51,66,71,84,99 but let's use above one) 
Convert it to the following low high form without using extra memory or a standard library

```
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5
```

A low-high form means that we use the smallest followed by highest. Then we use the second smallest and second-highest.

Initially, when he asked, I had used a secondary array and used the 2 pointer approach. I kept one pointer in front and the second pointer at last . then one by one I copied left and right data to my new array and then moved left as left ++ and right as  --right till they cross or become same.

After this, he asked me to do it without memory.

My approach to solving it without memory was on following lines . But it was confusing and not working

```
1) swap 2nd and last in **odd** (pos index 1)
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 becomes 
1,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,2
then we reach even 
2) swap 3rd and last in **even** (pos index 2 we are at 3 )
1,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,2 becomes (swapped 3 and 2_ )
1,9,2,4,5,6,7,8,3
and then sawp 8 and 3 
1,9,2,4,5,6,7,8,3 becomes 
1,9,2,4,5,6,7,3,8

3) we reach in odd (pos index 3 we are at 4 )
1,9,2,4,5,6,7,3,8
becomes 
1,9,2,8,5,6,7,3,4

4) swap even 5 to last 
and here it becomes wrong
```

Comment: Do you have a question, or are you literally asking Stackoverflow to complete a job interview for you?

Comment: Its a problem solving question, i guess from leetcode. Isn't it ?

Comment: @robin . a link will definitely help.

Comment: Are the elements guaranteed to be consecutive integers?

Comment: no. They are sorted elements .

Comment: Can't we even use one extra variable?

Comment: @Emalp I assume you can use O(1) extra memory.

Comment: @MAG check my answer, i try to solve with a simple way - And this is the similar type of question, i hope it will help you https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by pointing out that even registers are a kind of memory. Without any 'extra' memory (other than that occupied by the sorted array, that is) we don't even have counters! That said, here goes:

Let `a` be an array of `n > 2` positive integers sorted in ascending order, with the positions indexed from `0` to `n-1`.

From `i = 1` to `n-2`, bubble-sort the sub-array ranging from position `i` to position `n-1` (inclusive), alternatively in descending and ascending order. (Meaning that you bubble-sort in descending order if `i` is odd and in ascending order if it is even.)

Since to [bubble-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) you only need to compare, and possibly swap, adjacent elements, you won't need 'extra' memory.

(Mind you, if you start at `i = 0` and first sort in ascending order, you don't even need `a` to be pre-sorted.)

And one more thing: as there was no talk of it in your question, I will keep very silent on the performance of the above algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

We will make n/2 passes and during each pass we will swap each element, from left to right, starting with the element at position 2k-1, with the last element. Example:

```
  pass 1
  V
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,2
1,9,2,4,5,6,7,8,3
1,9,2,3,5,6,7,8,4
1,9,2,3,4,6,7,8,5
1,9,2,3,4,5,7,8,6
1,9,2,3,4,5,6,8,7
1,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

      pass 2
      V
1,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,9,2,8,4,5,6,7,3
1,9,2,8,3,5,6,7,4
1,9,2,8,3,4,6,7,5
1,9,2,8,3,4,5,7,6
1,9,2,8,3,4,5,6,7

          pass 3
          V
1,9,2,8,3,4,5,6,7
1,9,2,8,3,7,5,6,4
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,5,6

              pass 4
              V
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,5,6
1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5
```

This should take O(n^2) swaps and uses no extra memory beyond the counters involved.

The loop invariant to prove is that the first 2k+1 positions are correct after iteration k of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, assuming that with constant space complexity, we need to lose some of our time complexity, the following algorithm possibly works in O(n^2) time complexity.

I wrote this in python. I wrote it as quickly as possible so apologies for any syntactical errors.

```
 # s is the array passed.
def hi_low(s):
   last = len(s)
   for i in range(0, last, 2):
      if s[i+1] == None:
        break

      index_to_swap = last
      index_to_be_swapped = i+1

      while s[index_to_be_swapped] != s[index_to_swap]:
           # write your own swap func here
           swap(s[index_to_swap], s[index_to_swap-1])
           index_to_swap -=1
  return s
```

Quick explanation:

Suppose the initial list given to us is:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So in our program, initially,

```
     index_to_swap = last
```

meaning that it is pointing to 9, and

```
     index_to_be_swapped = i+1
```

is i+1, i.e one step ahead of our current loop pointer. [Also remember we're looping with a difference of 2].

So initially,

```
     i = 0
     index_to_be_swapped = 1
     index_to_swap = 9
```

and in the inner loop what we're checking is: until the values in both of these indexes are same, we keep on swapping 
       swap(s[index_to_swap], s[index_to_swap-1])

so it'll look like:

```
   # initially:
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
      ^             ^---index_to_swap
      ^-----index_to_be_swapped

    # after 1 loop
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8
     ^           ^-----index_to_swap
     ^----- index_to_be_swapped

   ... goes on until

   1 9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
     ^-----index_to_swap
     ^-----index_to_be_swapped
```

Now, the inner loop's job is done, and the main loop is run again with

```
 1 9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
     ^           ^---- index_to_swap
     ^------index_to_be_swapped
```

This runs until it's behind 2.

So the outer loop runs for almost n\2 times, and for each outer loop the inner loop runs for almost n\2 times in the worst case so the time complexity if n/2*n/2 = n^2/4 which is the order of n^2 i.e O(n^2).

If there are any mistakes please feel free to point it out.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

**It will work for any sorted array**

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let i = arr[0];
let j = arr[arr.length - 1];
let k = 0;

while(k < arr.length) {
  arr[k] = i;
  if(arr[k+1]) arr[k+1] = j;
  i++;
  k += 2;
  j--; 
}

console.log(arr);
```

**Explanation:** Because its a sorted array, you need to know 3 things to produce your expected output.

1. Starting Value : `let i = arr[0]`
2. Ending Value(You can also find it with the length of array by the way): `let j = arr[arr.length -1]`
3. Length of Array: `arr.length`

Loop through the array and set the value like this

`arr[firstIndex] = firstValue, arr[thirdIndex] = firstValue + 1 and so on..`

`arr[secondIndex] = lastValue, arr[fourthIndex] = lastValue - 1 and so on..`

Obviously you can do the same things in a different way. But i think that's the simplest way.

Comment: didnt worked for let arr = [1, 20, 30, 44, 50, 66, 78, 81, 900];

Comment: OH ! i thought any incremental sorted array.